# How to loop over multiple directories in python

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

How can i make this code to loop through all subdirectories of CHEST_ICONS
that includes directories and in the end there are some .dcm icons that I want to convert into jpg?
CHEST_ICONS includes CPTAC-SAR directory. CPTAC-SAR includes C3L-03196 and C3L-01038 each of them includes 1 more directory which includes the last directories with .dcm files.

```
folder_path = "...DcmFIles\CHEST_ICONS\CPTAC-SAR\C3L-01038\10-31-2011-ABDOMEN-42992\2-92491"
images_path = os.listdir(folder_path)
for n, image in enumerate(images_path):
    do stuff
```

Thanks in advance. Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to run listdir on each path within folder_path, or recursively all folders within CHEST_ICOSN?

Comment: @ollien I want to get to the lasts directories from each subdirectory and convert the .dcm files from them into jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper approach would be:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk( folder_path ) :
    # root is the current folder (somewhere down the tree)
    # dirs contains all subfolder names in the current folder
    # files has all file names in the current folder
    for f in files :
        print( os.path.join( root, f ) )  # ought to `.join()` to get the full name
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you `folder_path` is pointing to a file or directory further down than CHEST_ICONS. If you end at CHEST_ICONS then you can use `os.listdir()` recursively to hit any directories found after that point. Depending on how much is in the directories though your runtime could be very long...

Comment: Ye I know I just wanted to point out that I want to reach this directory and also the rest. Sorry if i've been misunderstood.

Comment: Ah, in that case it looks like lenik's answer is the best approach. I haven't seen the `os.walk()` method before. Very useful...